# Transform a Flexbox Row Columns items into Carousel for Mobile. Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mobile, slider

I have to make a Flexbox grid row for desktop and need to transform a carousel for mobile device. In desktop view it's show in a row and column structure using by Flexbox and show as a Carousel view in mobile by using JavaScript only. no jQuery or other third part plugins. Please find the full code in codepen https://codepen.io/pritambhadra/pen/QWGZjXv
https://codepen.io/pritambhadra/pen/QWGZjXv

`

```
                        <div class="fsm f-col  hide-user show-user">                    
                        <video class="video" autoplay loop muted webkit-playsinline="true" playsinline="true"><source src="https://toktown-v2-grid-framework.web.app/v4/Woman.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
                        <div class="user-info">
                        <div class="equlizer-wrapper">
                            <div class="equlizer-list">
                                <span class="step-one">&nbsp;</span>
                                <span class="step-two">&nbsp;</span>
                                <span class="step-three">&nbsp;</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="username">Pritam</div>
                        </div>                  
                        <div class="full"></div>                    
                        </div>

                        <div class="fsm f-col  hide-user show-user">                    
                        <video class="video" autoplay loop muted webkit-playsinline="true" playsinline="true"><source src="https://toktown-v2-grid-framework.web.app/v4/Woman.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
                        <div class="user-info">
                        <div class="equlizer-wrapper">
                        <div class="equlizer-list">
                            <span class="step-one">&nbsp;</span>
                            <span class="step-two">&nbsp;</span>
                            <span class="step-three">&nbsp;</span>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="username">Pritam</div>
                        </div>                  
                        <div class="full"></div>                    
                        </div>

                        <div class="fsm f-col  hide-user show-user">                    
                        <video class="video" autoplay webkit-playsinline="true" playsinline="true"><source src="https://toktown-v2-grid-framework.web.app/v4/Woman.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
                        <div class="user-info">
                        <div class="equlizer-wrapper">
                        <div class="equlizer-list">
                            <span class="step-one">&nbsp;</span>
                            <span class="step-two">&nbsp;</span>
                            <span class="step-three">&nbsp;</span>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="username">Pritam</div>
                        </div>                  
                        <div class="full"></div>                    
                        </div>

                        <div class="fsm f-col  hide-user show-user">                    
                        <video class="video" autoplay webkit-playsinline="true" playsinline="true"><source src="https://toktown-v2-grid-framework.web.app/v4/Woman.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
                        <div class="user-info">
                        <div class="equlizer-wrapper">
                        <div class="equlizer-list">
                            <span class="step-one">&nbsp;</span>
                            <span class="step-two">&nbsp;</span>
                            <span class="step-three">&nbsp;</span>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="username">Pritam</div>
                        </div>                  
                        <div class="full"></div>                    
                        </div>

                        <div class="fsm f-col  hide-user show-user">                    
                        <video class="video" autoplay webkit-playsinline="true" playsinline="true"><source src="https://toktown-v2-grid-framework.web.app/v4/Woman.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
                        <div class="user-info">
                        <div class="equlizer-wrapper">
                        <div class="equlizer-list">
                            <span class="step-one">&nbsp;</span>
                            <span class="step-two">&nbsp;</span>
                            <span class="step-three">&nbsp;</span>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="username">Pritam</div>
                        </div>                  
                        <div class="full"></div>                    
                        </div>

                        <div class="fsm f-col  hide-user show-user">                    
                        <video class="video" autoplay webkit-playsinline="true" playsinline="true"><source src="https://toktown-v2-grid-framework.web.app/v4/Woman.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
                        <div class="user-info">
                        <div class="equlizer-wrapper">
                        <div class="equlizer-list">
                            <span class="step-one">&nbsp;</span>
                            <span class="step-two">&nbsp;</span>
                            <span class="step-three">&nbsp;</span>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="username">Pritam</div>
                        </div>                  
                        <div class="full"></div>                    
                        </div>

                        <div class="fsm f-col  hide-user show-user">                    
                        <video class="video" autoplay webkit-playsinline="true" playsinline="true"><source src="https://toktown-v2-grid-framework.web.app/v4/Woman.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
                        <div class="user-info">
                        <div class="equlizer-wrapper">
                        <div class="equlizer-list">
                            <span class="step-one">&nbsp;</span>
                            <span class="step-two">&nbsp;</span>
                            <span class="step-three">&nbsp;</span>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="username">Pritam</div>
                        </div>                  
                        <div class="full"></div>                    
                        </div>

                        <div class="fsm f-col  hide-user show-user">                    
                        <video class="video" autoplay webkit-playsinline="true" playsinline="true"><source src="https://toktown-v2-grid-framework.web.app/v4/Woman.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
                        <div class="user-info">
                        <div class="equlizer-wrapper">
                        <div class="equlizer-list">
                            <span class="step-one">&nbsp;</span>
                            <span class="step-two">&nbsp;</span>
                            <span class="step-three">&nbsp;</span>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="username">Pritam</div>
                        </div>                  
                        <div class="full"></div>                    
                        </div>              

                        <div class="fsm f-col  hide-share-scrn show-share-scrn">
                        <video class="video" autoplay webkit-playsinline="true" playsinline="true"><source src="https://toktown-v2-grid-framework.web.app/v4/file_example.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video> 
                        <div class="user-info">                         
                        <div class="username">Share Screen One</div>
                        </div>                  
                        <div class="full"></div>                    
                        </div>               

                    </div> 
                </div>
            </div> `
```